# Java HTML parsing (storing as String)

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing a web page, but I got some problem, the page consists a lot of such elements:

```
<div class="tweet">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Sweden" target="_blank" class="tweet__link">@sweden</a>
        <span class="tweet__timestamp"><a href="https://twitter.com/sweden/status/694285861026926594" target="_blank" class="tweet__permalink">Feb. 1, 2016, 11:27 p.m.</a></span>
        <p class="tweet__content"><a href='http://twitter.com/UnbatedFlunky' target='_blank'>@UnbatedFlunky</a> Good to know. :)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tweet">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Sweden" target="_blank" class="tweet__link">@sweden</a>
        <span class="tweet__timestamp"><a href="https://twitter.com/sweden/status/694285696140513280" target="_blank" class="tweet__permalink">Feb. 1, 2016, 11:26 p.m.</a></span>
        <p class="tweet__content">RT <a href='http://twitter.com/UnbatedFlunky' target='_blank'>@UnbatedFlunky</a>: .<a href='http://twitter.com/sweden' target='_blank'>@sweden</a> exactly the kind of content I'd want representing my country. 10/10</p>
    </div>
```

I want to put the content in each tweet class in separate string, I have so far this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://curatorsofsweden.com/curator/aleksandra-boscanin/").get();
        Element e = doc.select("div").first();
            String text = doc.getElementsByClass("tweet").text();
```

but in this way I am storing all the content in one single string, but my question is how I can put them separately for example lets say String array :/ Maybe its a stupid question but  I could not make it work :/

Comment: Have you considered creating a Model first, then trying to serialize it?

Comment: what do you mean by model :/

Comment: It's an entity (in OOP) that mirrors the HTML (DOM) structure. You should read up on serialization and de-serialization. The Apache Xerces would be an easy framework to implement for deserializing HTML into classes: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html#faq-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.getElementsByClass("tweet")` returns an array over which you should iterate and create an array entry for each of the `tweet` elements. For example

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Element> tweets = doc.getElementsByClass("tweet");
for(Element tweet : tweets){
    stringList.add(tweet.text()); 
}
```

the texts will be in the `stringList` list.